# What application control request to pull content from Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, rss

On my site, I allowed members to register the address of their Facebook page to automatically display their public posts.

It worked very well. I had the **Page Public Content Access** permission.

But the authorization, after several years, was withdrawn from me. According to Facebook, it is only approved for statistical purposes. Facebook recommends the "Oembed read" permission to me. All right, I got it. But she does not meet my needs !

According to their documentation, it would not be possible to extract information from Facebook outside of oEmbed.

Ah ? However, by searching on Google "**Facebook to rss**", we find many websites which, without even registering, offer this. [This website](https://fetchrss.com/facebook), for example. So how do they do it?

I wrote it to Facebook support, who answered next to the question.

So how do you do it? How can I offer my members to automatically publish the publications of their page on our portal?

Comment: Unless that site you mentioned has some sort of deal with Facebook, they should not be able to do this any more either - other than by _scraping_ the pages.

Comment: The correct way to do this for your app, would be to ask your app users for access to the pages they manage - and then use a page access token for the request to fetch data from that specific page.

Comment: Thanks @CBroe. But the validity period of the token will not force you to repeat the operation several times ?

Comment: Page tokens can be extended to be valid for up to 60 days. You'll probably have to set up some sort of reminder/notification process, so that your users can come back and create a new token, when the existing one has expired.

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately this will not work with our audience, which at best only connects once a year to the platform. Too bad not being able to do as before. I therefore note that "facebook to rss" type sites are certainly outlawed. Anyway, thank you for your help.